# Number of rounds to find out the winner in nondeterministic game

Tags: statistics, game-theory

Imagine, I'm organizing competition for AI Yahtzee players (or some other game, poker, backgammon etc.). I want to find out who plays better: player A or player B. If they play just one game, winner could win because he plays better, or because it's just luck. So they need to play several games to find out the winner.

And I have two questions:

- how many games they should play? (More is better, but how much is enough?)
- what percentage if wins is enough to determine winner? (For example 46% to 54% seems like draw, and 76% to 24% seems like victory, but this is just an intuition.)

I understand, there is no exact answer here, but what are general methods to use? What should I measure to give the answer? (I can have any number of "warmup" games between A and B).

Comment: It depends in what your measuring. For example if you want to measure who can run faster then you won't need many matches, if however you want to measure something like poker or chess, then you will need more games.

Comment: @Omnitic Yes, but how much more?

Comment: Well, mathematics requires a set of rigid and exact laws. On the other hand: in the real world the condition better than doesn't really exist. What does it mean for someone to be better than the other? That definition is not mathematical, and because of that you can't work with it. You would have to give a definition for what "better" means,once you have given a mathematical meaning to the relation better than then you can work with the term mathematically.

Comment: @Omnitic Speaking mathematically, I want to measure statistical probability that A beats B with high confidence level.

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly you want to see how many games are required so that if they are to face themeselves again then you are pretty sure the winner will beat the loser again?

Comment: @Omnitic Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run statistical hypothesis tests on the share of wins of one player. But to be honest I doubt this is very practical, unless you plan to let these players play more than 20 games or so. Also, you cannot figure out "for certain" who the better player is. Assuming the outcome of these games is somewhat random, even a world class player can lose 10 times in a row to a complete amateur, although the probability of this happening is very slim (but not zero).

Assume that the outcome of games $g=1,2,\ldots n$ between two players $A$ and $B$ are independent (i.e., no daily shape etc.). Denote by $x_g\in\{0,1\}$ the outcome of game $g$ ($x_g=1$ if and only if player $A$ won).

Now the share of games won for player $A$ is the mean $s(A,B,n)=n^{-1}\sum_{g=1}^n x_g$. You can now run statistical, nonparametric tests that the true share $s$ is equal to 1/2,i.e., that both players are equally strong (equally likely to win). To do this, you can compute [confidence intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) of the mean $s(A,B)$ at, say, the conventional 95% level. To do this, just compute the [standard error $SE$ of the mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean), then the 95% confidence interval would be
$$CI=s(A,B,n)\pm 1.96 SE.$$
The standard error is $SE=\sigma/\sqrt{n}$, where $\sigma=\sqrt{s(A,B,n)(1-s(A,B,n))}$ is the standard deviation of the mean. Clearly, the SE becomes smaller as more games are played, and the confidence interval becomes narrower. This reflects the fact that with more games we are more confident that the *true* $s$ (which you would only obtain by letting the players play $n\to\infty$ games) is close to the sample mean $s(A,B,n)$. This is why I mentioned you might have to let these players play a lot of games before you can say, with a reasonable degree of confidence, that one is better than the other.

For small $n$, the 1.96 should be replaced by the respective critical value of the t-distribution, which is larger (here I assumed $n$ is large, so the value converges to the corresponding value of the standard normal distribution).

The test is now very simple. If $1/2\notin [\underline{CI},\overline{CI}]$, then you reject the hypothesis that the players are equally strong at the 95% level. You can also more directly test the hypothesis $s>1/2$ or $s<1/2$ ($A$ better than $B$, or $B$ better than $A$).

Just to get an idea, here's an example. Suppose players played 10 games, $n=10$, and $s(A,B,10)=0.6$. Accordingly, $[\underline{CI},\overline{CI}]=[0.296,0.903]$, so the CI is still very broad. Indeed, it requires about $n=100$ so that $\underline{CI}>1/2$, which would allow you to reject the hypothesis that players are equally strong with 95% confidence. In short, everything I described here tells you for $s(A,B,n)$ close to 1 or 0 with $n$ relatively large that this player is better, but you know that also without all those formulae.

My advice, just stick to rules of thumb: whoever has more wins after 10 games is better. Statistically, that player is more likely to be the better player, even though we may not be very confident for so few games about that (see example).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, it is AI competition (players are just computer programs), and one game doesn't take a lot of time. So I can have large number of games, for instance, 1000 games takes a couple of minutes in my case. So can you explain please how can I run "statistical hypothesis tests" for more exact results?

Comment: Ok if you can generate data then this makes sense. Just search the web for "hypothesis test mean". The easiest way may be to use a statistics program and run t-tests for $n=50$ or larger. Here is a more detailed description: http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/mean.aspx